# How to determine active panelBarItem in RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using the RichFaces `panelBar` and would like to determine the active `panelBarItem` at any given point in time. Could you suggest a way of doing so?

Thanks in advance!
MD

Answer (score 2):

There is a `selectedPanel` property which holds the id of the current item.